# Localization in the hmc structure

Tags: xml, properties, localization, structure, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a problem.
I have this part of *hmc.xml* structure:

```
<type name="Order" mode="append"> <!-- LOLLO -->
        <organizer>
            <search mode="append">
                <condition attribute="versionID" operator="is null" />
            </search>
            <editor mode="append">
                <tab name="positions_and_prices" position="0" mode="append">
                    <section name="original_totals" position="1" mode="append">
                        <listlayout>
                            <attribute name="subTotalOriginal" descriptionattribute="currency" labelwidth="530" width="124">
                                <doubleeditor>
                                    <parameter key="align" value="right"/>
                                </doubleeditor>
                            </attribute>
                            <attribute name="totalDiscountsOriginal" descriptionattribute="currency" labelwidth="530" width="124">
                                <doubleeditor>
                                    <parameter key="align" value="right"/>
                                </doubleeditor>
                            </attribute>
```

I would translate the section *original_totals*.
I tried adding a code like

> section.original_totals=OriginalTotals

but nothing happens.
How can I reference this section?
Here there is a screenshot of the structure:

[image]

Comment: This should work, I see your hmc.xml does not reference the whole variable, name="original_totals" and not name="section.original_totals"...

Comment: So you say that with name="section.original_totals" I can reference this part? I try thank you!!

Comment: Yes this is how the hmc.xml in the hmc extension itself references these values.

Comment: Thank you! This works! If you write this in an answer I'll choose your answer as right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *hmc.xml* you reference *original_totals* this should be *section.original_totals* leading to: *name="section.original_totals"*. If you overwrite/extend existing functionality and you are not sure how to declare your code it is always a good habit to look for the original files, in this case the hmc.xml in the hmc extension.